# How to calculate the time complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

anybody can help to explain why this function

F(n) = F(n/3) + 1 with F(0) = 0

Can have time complexity of O(Log n) with log base 3.

Is there a mathematical notation or anything that can help explain to me how to get the result. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By substitution, it can be done simply:

```
F(n) = F(n/3) + 1 = F(n/3^2) + 1 + 1 = 1 + 1 + ... + 1 (log_3(n) times)
```

As each time `n` is divided by `3` and `1` is added to the result, if we suppose `n = 3^k`, `F(n) = k`. Hence, `F(n) = O(log(n))`. The constant (>1) in the base of the logarithm has not any impact on the order of complexity, i.e., `log_a(n) = Theta(log_b(n))` (`a,b > 1`).

Comment: alright thankyou for your answer. appreciate it @OmG